# Alternatives to IF statement with multiple OR

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a HTML form with a file upload option where I do a quick validation of the file format on client side (in order to allow only certain file extensions).

The following code snippet works fine for me but I was wondering if there is a better or faster way to achieve the same, esp. if there are more extensions to be allowed in the future.

Note: This is only about the part with the multiple OR statements to check the file extension.

**My code so far (working):**

```
if( ( (fileNameShort.length <= 100) && (fileNameShort.indexOf('#') == -1) ) && ( (fileFormat == 'bmp') || (fileFormat == 'doc') || (fileFormat == 'docx') || (fileFormat == 'gif') || (fileFormat == 'jpeg') || (fileFormat == 'jpg') || (fileFormat == 'msg') || (fileFormat == 'png') || (fileFormat == 'pdf') ) )
```

Many thanks for any suggestions on this, Tim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

and also use [.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) as checking for lowercase file formats

```
var arr=['bmp','doc','docx','gif','jpg','msg']; //create array filetypes

if(fileNameShort.length <= 100 && fileNameShort.indexOf('#') === -1 && arr.indexOf(fileFormat.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
```

Comment: This is perfect - thanks a lot for the quick reply. I will accept once it is available.

Answer (score 3):

You are using *way* too may parentheses.

```
if ( 
  ( 
    ( fileNameShort.length <= 100 ) 
    && ( fileNameShort.indexOf('#') == -1 ) 
  ) 
  && 
  ( 
    (fileFormat == 'bmp') || (fileFormat == 'doc') || (fileFormat == 'docx') || (fileFormat == 'gif') || (fileFormat == 'jpeg') || (fileFormat == 'jpg') || (fileFormat == 'msg') || (fileFormat == 'png') || (fileFormat == 'pdf') 
  ) 
)
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( 
  fileNameShort.length <= 100 
  && fileNameShort.indexOf('#') == -1
  && ( 
    fileFormat == 'bmp' || fileFormat == 'doc' || fileFormat == 'docx' || fileFormat == 'gif' || fileFormat == 'jpeg' || fileFormat == 'jpg' || fileFormat == 'msg' || fileFormat == 'png' || fileFormat == 'pdf'
  ) 
)
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( 
  fileNameShort.length <= 100 
  && fileNameShort.indexOf('#') == -1
  && /^(bmp|docx?|gif|jpe?g|msg|png|pdf)$/i.test(fileFormat)
)
```